# Why is the transfer function of this non-inverting low-pass filter wrong?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, active-filter, step-response

I came across this block in a larger circuit:

[image: schematic]

With a transfer function (in pole-zero form) of; 
$$
H(s) = \frac{s+30000}{s+5000}
$$
which was found using KCL on the inverting terminal of the op-amp.

As I am not used to finding transfer functions using conventional circuit analysis and I wanted to find the "pure" transfer function (i.e. the general function not the pole-zero representation). However I found that substituting my transfer function in the place of the pole-zero, with a step response is not quite the same. (It also does not match simulation outputs compared to the pole-zero function)

My calculations are as follows:

$$
V^{+}=V_{in}=V^{-}=V_{out}\times\frac{R_{2}}{\frac{1}{sC}||R_{1}+R_{2}}
$$
$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{\frac{\frac{R_{1}}{sC}}{\frac{1}{sC}+R_{1}}+R_{2}}{R_{2}}=1 + \frac{\frac{R_{1}}{sC}}{R_{2}(\frac{1}{sC}+R_{1})}=1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\times\frac{{sC}}{{sC}}\times\frac{1}{1+R_{1}Cs}
$$
From this I found the final transfer function to be:
$$
H(s)=K\frac{1}{1+R_{1}Cs},\:\:\text{where}\:\:K=1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\:\:\text{and}\:\:\omega_{p}=\frac{1}{R_{1}C}
$$
The K value was derived from the DC gain of a non-inverting amplifier and the pole frequency equation was derived from the relationship shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency

For the transfer function of the larger circuit; this block's transfer function is multiplied with another (an RL filter is connected to the input of the op-amp);
$$
T(s)=\frac{s}{s+\frac{R}{L}},\:\:R=80\Omega,\:\:L=10\text{mH},\:\:T(s)=\frac{s}{s+8000}
$$
$$
H(s)\times T(s)=\frac{s(s+30000)}{(s+5000)(s+8000)} - \text{Using pole-zero function}
$$
$$H(s)\times T(s)=\frac{30000s}{(s+5000)(s+8000)} - \text{Using transfer function}
$$
The transfer function was then given a step function \$ \frac{0.6}{s} \$ and then simplified with partial fractions:
$$
H(s)=\frac{5}{s+5000}-\frac{4.4}{s+8000} - \text{Using pole-zero function}
$$
$$
H(s)=\frac{6}{s+5000}-\frac{6}{s+8000} - \text{Using transfer function}
$$
Here is the graph of the two inverse laplace functions' step response:
[image]

My question is this; is the "pure" transfer function I derived wrong or is there some error made afterwards that results in an incorrect final graph compared to the pole-zero one? The pole frequency equation is correct and the general form of the transfer function matches a low-pass so I am most confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transfer function of the non-inverting circuit (which is **no lowpass**) is not correct. There is a simple math error.

The correct expression is:

**Vout/Vin=1+ (R1/R2)*[1/(1+sR1C1)]**

Hence, for s approaching infinity, the transfer function is approaching "1" (and not zero).

Comment: So instead of \$K=1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\:\text{it should be}\:H(s)=1+K\frac{1}{1+sR_{1}C},\:\text{where}\:K=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\$?

Comment: The Vout/Vin in your answer is the same as the Vin/Vout as OP!!

Comment: The zero is missing in your expression LvW.

Comment: @Verbal Kint...do you mean that the transfer function is not correct? I do not understand your comment. Of course, the zero is contained in the expression - but not visible without rewriting the formula.

Comment: False alarm, I missed the parenthesis after the +: entschuldigung : )

Answer (score 2):

Your transfer function \$ \frac {V_{out} }{ V_{in} } \$ is correct.

However, the error is in the following:

$$H(s)=1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{1+R_{1}Cs}
\neq \bigg(1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}} \bigg)\frac{1}{1+R_{1}Cs}$$

You are also right that the DC gain is

$$H(0)=1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{1+R_{1}Cs} = 1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}$$

There is a pole<sup>1)</sup> at \$ \omega_p = \frac{ 1 }{ R_1C } \$. You can not simply conclude that from the transfer function above. Better to rewrite the transfer function as a \$ \text{gain factor} \times \frac{ \text{polynomial with zeros} }{ \text{polynomial with poles} }\$:

$$H(s) = 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2} \cdot \frac{ 1 }{ 1+R_{1}Cs }$$

$$H(s) = 1 + \frac{ R_1 }{ R_2+R_1 R_2 Cs }$$

$$H(s) = \frac{ R_2+R_1 R_2 Cs }{ R_2+R_1 R_2 Cs } + \frac{ R_1 }{ R_2+R_1 R_2 Cs }$$

$$H(s) = \frac{ 1}{ R_2} \frac{ (R_1 + R_2) + R_1 R_2 Cs }{ 1 + R_1 Cs }$$

The pole lies indeed at
$$ s = \frac{ 1 }{ R_1 C } $$

**EDIT**
<sup>1)</sup> As LvW correctly mentions the cut-off frequency \$ \omega_c\$ is NOT identical to the pole frequency \$ \omega_p=\frac{ 1 }{ R_1 C } \$. This would be true for a real lowpass only.

Comment: So what would the K value of the transfer function be in this case?

Comment: @NBoss What is K? The gain of the transfer function?

Comment: Yes, for an inverting amplifier transfer function the K is usually \$-\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}}\$ is there such as K value in this case?

Comment: @Huisman....you are wrong. Please check the unit of your pole frequency expression. The pole frequency is as given by NBoss.

Comment: @LvW thanks, I see. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @NBoss Although K  is just another variable, one *could* define a general expression for a 1st order low-pass filter as \$ H(j \omega) = \frac{ K }{ 1 + j \omega / \omega_c } \$. But this isn't a 1st order low-pass filter, so, here an expression of K would be meaningless.

Comment: @Huisman....there is another error: For the given circuit, the cut-off frequency wc is NOT identical to the pole frequency wp=1/R1C1.. This would be true for a real lowpass only. However, the given circuit is not a classical 1st-order lowpass - it has an s-element in the numerator which makes that wc is not equal to wp. Here, calculation of wc is rather involved (we must find the magnitude of the complete function)

Answer (score 2):

This simple circuit features a pole and a zero. It is important to express the transfer function in a *low-entropy* form so that the pole and the zero clearly appear as well as the dc gain. The way to write it in this way would be: \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$.

There are many ways to determine this expression but I personally favor the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371): determine the dc gain \$H_0\$ when the capacitor is open-circuited (\$s=0\$). Then set the excitation to 0 V (replace the source by a short circuit) and determine the resistance \$R\$ "seen" from the capacitor terminals in this mode. This will give you the natural time constant \$RC_1\$ and the pole is the inverse of the time constant in a 1st-order system. For the zero, simply replace the cap. by a short circuit and determine the gain \$H^1\$ in this mode:

[image]

Once you have these values on hand, capture them in a solver like Mathcad, rearrange to fit the aforementioned format and voilà:

[image]

I added the cutoff frequency calculation as well as the phase minimum.